# Страница "Технические работы" на сервере kestrel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, nginx, asp.net-core, kestrel

Есть приложение на asp .net core 2 и размещаемое на сервере kestrel через nginx. Как можно настроить, чтобы во время обновления при публикации приложении, когда оно остановлено, выводилась статическая страница "технические работы" ? Как оно в принципе реализуется в таких случаях и на каком уровне настраивается роутинг?

Comment: На уровне nginx через правила

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page